# How can I restrict users from creating views in the Datasheet view in SP 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, user, datasheet

I need to restrict users (with Contribute rights) ability to create Datasheet view. Also, how may I disable Quick Edit mode in all views?

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a custom permission, and in that permission uncheck the `Manage Lists` option under `List Permissions`, or perhaps the `Manage Personal Views` option under `Personal Permissions`, then give those users that new permission?  Custom permissions can be created in Site Actions->Site Settings->Site Permissions, then click Permission Levels at the top in the Manage section of the ribbon.

This article might help as well: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ca95a6e1-747b-4631-bbcc-bdd5a1102a22/disabling-create-view-for-sharepoint-discussion-forum?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Answer (score 0):

Here you able find the URL with clear explanation.

http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2016/06/how-to-restrict-users-for-creating.html